# not able to pass the argument on runnable class with @Component property

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have `StandardizedAddressRepository` class with `@Component` property

```
@Component
public class StandardizedAddressRepository implements Runnable {

public StandardizedAddressRepository(BufferedReader reader, SqsMessage sqsMessage) throws IOException {
}
}
```

Question:
how can I pass argument to `StandardizedAddressRepository`?
I can able to pass argument without @Component property but I don't want to remove it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `@Autowired` on head of constructor `@Autowired public StandardizedAddressRepository(BufferedReader reader, SqsMessage sqsMessage) throws IOException {
}`

Comment: I added @Autowired it's not working

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: could not autowire. No beans of 'BufferedReader' type found.

Comment: Of course! `BufferedReader` was not injected as `component` then you should create a `@Bean public BufferedReader getBufferedReader() { return new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in")); }` in a configurator class which has `@Configuration` as annotation.

Comment: I don't have `@Configuration` annotation but I have `@SpringBootApplication` in my main class.

Comment: So create one configurator with that annotation...  and add that bean!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206371/discussion-between-jay-kakadiya-and-one-guy).

Comment: `@Configuration` will works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `Configurator` class in order to inject the dependencies for `BufferedReader` and `SqsMessage` classes as well. Your code should look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Configurator {

    @Bean
    public BufferedReader bufferedReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""));
    }

    @Bean
    public SqsMessage sqsMessage(){
        return new SqsMessage();
    }

}
```